# Does electropolishing has any effect on the conductivity of stainless steel?

Tags: metallurgy

During the manufacturing of a spring from SS AISI 303 wire, we noticed that after electropolishing, the sample does not remain as conductive as it was before. My hypothesis is that since electropolishing reveals a chromium enriched surface, which further interacts with the oxygen to form a continuous layer of Cr<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> which is semi-conductive in nature and hence our conductivity decreases?
Is there any literature that can help?

Comment: A multimeter should be enough to measure resistivity aka inverse of conductivity.  Once you have a measure, you can experiment to find the truth and publish it... or stamp it proprietary. And hide it